When I know the answer to who published a poem, such as "Don't Care" by William Blake, how come I I'm not allowed provide this simple answer?
When I know the answer to who published a poem, such as "Don't Care" by William Blake, how come I am not allowed provide a simple answer?

Can you explain what you mean? I don't see such a question on this site. Did you mean to post this somewhere else?

Also, what do you mean by "not allowed" - did you just hit the minimum length validation? Was there another content violation? Were you told by somebody to avoid answering?

Did you attempt to put an answer in a comment instead of an answer post?  That is not permitted.
